# How to traverse a dict in python and make two separate dict out of it?

Tags: python

```
data = "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (-8.9648437500000000 -4.1308593750000000), POINT (2.0214843750000000 -2.6367187500000000), POINT (-1.4062500000000000 -11.1621093750000000), POINT (-11.9531250000000000,-10.8984375000000000), POLYGON ((-21.6210937500000000 1.8457031250000000,2.4609375000000000 2.1972656250000000, -18.9843750000000000 -3.6914062500000000, -22.6757812500000000 -3.3398437500000000, -22.1484375000000000 -2.6367187500000000, -21.6210937500000000 1.8457031250000000)),LINESTRING (-11.9531250000000000 11.3378906250000000, 7.7343750000000000 11.5136718750000000, 12.3046875000000000 2.5488281250000000, 12.2167968750000000 1.6699218750000000, 14.5019531250000000 3.9550781250000000))"
```

Out of this I want to create 3 separate dicts . Point . Polygon . LineString . 
And for each Point = {co-ord1, cord2, cord3...} 
Similary for the Polygon and LineString . Whats the best way to do it ?

I want to create 3 separate variables out of this . 
One is Point that has all the co-ordinates . Same with Polygon and LineString .

Comment: maybe not 3 dicts but one dict with 3 keys "Point", "Polygon", and "LineString"?

Comment: @Roman: Correct me if I'm wrong, but one dict with three keys would only allow him to store one Point, Polygon, and LineString.

Comment: @Greg, it could be a dict of string to list of tuples, a tuple for each point, coors or whatever... but the question isn't clear at all.

Comment: @Roman: And now that the question has been updated, I stand corrected.

Comment: @user794916 could you express the data in some kind of python data structure?

Comment: Downvoting isn't really helping here . See , my form is returning exactly the data that I have posted and I am storing it in a variable Data . Now , out of the variable data , I want to iterate through it and generate 3 lists/dict . One list for Point , one for Polygon , one for LineString .

Comment: Obviously the data that I have is not in dict . That is the biggest problem here , which is why I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you can make sure to separate all the numbers by a `,`, then it is possible to do what I think you want to do with some simple python classes and the `eval` function. Basically, define a class for each of `POINT`, `POLYGON` and so on. With this, you can turn your string into an expression that makes a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION object out of POINT, POLYGON, LINESTRING objects. Bear in mind that in your string it would be better to define coords as size-2 tuples, `((A,B), (C,D))` instead of `(A B, C, D)`. If you can do that, then the rest is

```
class Coords(object) :
    """
    Simple base class, stores ctor arguments as a tuple.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args) :
        self.coords = tuple(args)

class POINT(Coords) :
    """
    Dummy class, to have handle on class name.
    """
    pass

# similar definitions for POLYGON and LINESTRING

class GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(object) :
    def __init__(self, *args) :
        self.data = {} #store data in a type name -> coord tuple map
        for arg in args:
            if type(arg).__name__ not in self.data.keys() :
                self.data[type(arg).__name__] = [arg.coords]
            else :
                self.data[type(arg).__name__].append(arg.coords)
    def __getitem__(self,key) :
        # allow access via [] operator
        return self.data.get(key)
```

Then in your code (once you have fixed the string to the format I suggested)

```
data = "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (-8.9648437500000000,  ......"
geom = eval(data)
point_coords = geom['POINT']
```

and so on. This is a bit of a hack, I'm sure there are more elegant ways of achieving this.

This line would result in two POINT coordinates and one POLYGON:

```
data="GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (-8.9648437500000000, -4.1308593750000000), POINT (2.0214843750000000, -2.6367187500000000), POLYGON ((-21.6210937500000000, 1.8457031250000000),(2.4609375000000000, 2.1972656250000000), (-18.9843750000000000, -3.6914062500000000), (-22.6757812500000000, -3.3398437500000000)))"
```

Comment: That's probably because of a lack of commas in `data`. Make sure to separate all numbers by a `,` and group numbers together in `(` and `)` if you need a logical separation.

Comment: I've added an example data string.

Comment: There is again a small problem there . The string is not really under my control . When it goes into the site , it will be just be a generic variable .

Comment: Then it is complicated. The question is more about parsing a string than traversing a dict though. If the string isn't valid python, then you have to write some special parsing code.

Comment: That could be an option, but I'm not sure how maintainable and scalable that would be. Your best bet is to get the data string into some kind of useful and consistent syntax.